# Find Index size in sql server

Tags: sql-server, index, database-internals

The following two queries return different values for index size.

```
SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
i.name AS IndexName,
i.index_id AS IndexID,
8 * SUM(a.used_pages) AS 'Indexsize(KB)'
FROM sys.indexes AS i
JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND p.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
GROUP BY i.OBJECT_ID,i.index_id,i.name
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID),i.index_id
```

And

```
sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?''''
```

Can anyone suggest exact query to find Index size for each tables **from system views** in sql server?

Comment: No,I need a query to find index size from system views @JoeObbish

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at this question here:
[space usage on sys.allocation_units and sp_spaceused](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84333/space-usage-on-sys-allocation-units-and-sp-spaceused)

You will fin this script below, that will tell you teh size of your indexes.

```
;WITH agg AS
(   -- Get info for Tables, Indexed Views, etc
    SELECT  ps.[object_id] AS [ObjectID],
            ps.index_id AS [IndexID],
            NULL AS [ParentIndexID],
            NULL AS [PassThroughIndexName],
            NULL AS [PassThroughIndexType],
            SUM(ps.in_row_data_page_count) AS [InRowDataPageCount],
            SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS [UsedPageCount],
            SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS [ReservedPageCount],
            SUM(ps.row_count) AS [RowCount],
            SUM(ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                    AS [LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount]
    FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
    GROUP BY    ps.[object_id],
                ps.[index_id]
    UNION ALL
    -- Get info for FullText indexes, XML indexes, Spatial indexes, etc
    SELECT  sit.[parent_id] AS [ObjectID],
            sit.[object_id] AS [IndexID],
            sit.[parent_minor_id] AS [ParentIndexID],
            sit.[name] AS [PassThroughIndexName],
            sit.[internal_type_desc] AS [PassThroughIndexType],
            0 AS [InRowDataPageCount],
            SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS [UsedPageCount],
            SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS [ReservedPageCount],
            0 AS [RowCount],
            0 AS [LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount]
    FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
    INNER JOIN  sys.internal_tables sit
            ON  sit.[object_id] = ps.[object_id]
    WHERE   sit.internal_type IN
               (202, 204, 207, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 221, 222, 236)
    GROUP BY    sit.[parent_id],
                sit.[object_id],
                sit.[parent_minor_id],
                sit.[name],
                sit.[internal_type_desc]
), spaceused AS
(
SELECT  agg.[ObjectID],
        agg.[IndexID],
        agg.[ParentIndexID],
        agg.[PassThroughIndexName],
        agg.[PassThroughIndexType],
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(agg.[ObjectID]) AS [SchemaName],
        OBJECT_NAME(agg.[ObjectID]) AS [TableName],
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN (agg.IndexID < 2) THEN agg.[RowCount]
                ELSE 0
            END) AS [Rows],
        SUM(agg.ReservedPageCount) * 8 AS [ReservedKB],
        SUM(agg.LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount +
            CASE
                WHEN (agg.IndexID < 2) THEN (agg.InRowDataPageCount)
                ELSE 0
            END) * 8 AS [DataKB],
        SUM(agg.UsedPageCount - agg.LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount -
            CASE
                WHEN (agg.IndexID < 2) THEN agg.InRowDataPageCount
                ELSE 0
            END) * 8 AS [IndexKB],
        SUM(agg.ReservedPageCount - agg.UsedPageCount) * 8 AS [UnusedKB],
        SUM(agg.UsedPageCount) * 8 AS [UsedKB]
FROM    agg
GROUP BY    agg.[ObjectID],
            agg.[IndexID],
            agg.[ParentIndexID],
            agg.[PassThroughIndexName],
            agg.[PassThroughIndexType],
            OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(agg.[ObjectID]),
            OBJECT_NAME(agg.[ObjectID])
)
SELECT sp.SchemaName,
       sp.TableName,
       sp.IndexID,
       IIF(sp.IndexID > 0, COALESCE(si.[name], sp.[PassThroughIndexName]), N'<Heap>')
             AS [IndexName],
       sp.[PassThroughIndexName] AS [InternalTableName],
       sp.[Rows],
       sp.ReservedKB,
       (sp.ReservedKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [ReservedGB],
       sp.DataKB,
       (sp.DataKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [DataGB],
       sp.IndexKB,
       (sp.IndexKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [IndexGB],
       sp.UsedKB AS [UsedKB],
       (sp.UsedKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [UsedGB],
       sp.UnusedKB,
       (sp.UnusedKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [UnusedGB],
       so.[type_desc] AS [ObjectType],
       COALESCE(si.type_desc, sp.[PassThroughIndexType]) AS [IndexPrimaryType],
       sp.[PassThroughIndexType] AS [IndexSecondaryType],
       SCHEMA_ID(sp.[SchemaName]) AS [SchemaID],
       sp.ObjectID
       --,sp.ParentIndexID
FROM   spaceused sp
INNER JOIN sys.objects so
        ON so.[object_id] = sp.ObjectID
LEFT JOIN  sys.indexes si
       ON  si.[object_id] = sp.ObjectID
      AND  (si.[index_id] = sp.IndexID
         OR si.[index_id] = sp.[ParentIndexID])
WHERE so.is_ms_shipped = 0
--so.[name] LIKE N''  -- optional name filter
--ORDER BY ????
```

Comment: Then why the sp_spaceused procedure show the size totally different? @marcello miorelli