# What is using all my space?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

I'm using SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and a third part application has its database on this database server.  The database seems way bigger than I would expect considering what it is actually doing.  When I do a rough add up of the space used by the tables and indexes I get to about half of the total size of the database file.

I am wondering what is using up the rest of the space.  I understand SQL Server Express is limited to 10GB which is why I'm concerned as the database is about 2/3 full. I also understand that there is free space within the database itself which is no problem.  I'm not short of disk space.

Here is how I have found the size of the tables and indexes.  I don't understand these queries very well as I googled them but they seem to report the numbers I'm interested in:

```
-- Size of database and how much space is used
SELECT
(SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(CAST(df.size as float))*8/1024.0)
   FROM sys.database_files AS df 
   WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) ) AS [DbSize],
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(a.total_pages)*8/1024.0) AS [SpaceUsed],
(SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(CAST(df.size as float))*8/1024.0)
   FROM sys.database_files AS df 
   WHERE df.type in (1, 3)) AS [LogSize]
FROM sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a 
  on p.partition_id = a.container_id;
```

Result:

```
DbSize   SpaceUsed  LogSize
-------  ---------  -------
7829.25    6130.09   611.13
```

OK so what is using that 6.1 GB?

The following query lists the sizes of all the tables and indexes ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database#17600911)):

```
;with cte as (
SELECT
t.name as TableName,
SUM (s.used_page_count) as used_pages_count,
SUM (CASE
            WHEN (i.index_id < 2) THEN (in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count)
            ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
        END) as pages
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats  AS s 
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON s.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.[object_id] = t.[object_id] AND s.index_id = i.index_id
GROUP BY t.name
)
select
    cte.TableName, 
    cast((cte.pages * 8.)/1024 as decimal(10,3)) as TableSizeInMB, 
    cast(((CASE WHEN cte.used_pages_count > cte.pages 
                THEN cte.used_pages_count - cte.pages
                ELSE 0 
          END) * 8./1024) as decimal(10,3)) as IndexSizeInMB
from cte
order by 2 desc
```

If I add up all the tables and indexes with a size over 1mb, it comes to under 3GB in total.  (I tried sum in the above query but couldn't figure that out)

If I post the full output here it is very long and messy.

So it seems about half of the expected free space is being used up by something else.

Any ideas what I'm missing here or, do I need a better way to add up used space?

Comment: I often use this query : [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84333/space-usage-on-sys-allocation-units-and-sp-spaceused](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84333/space-usage-on-sys-allocation-units-and-sp-spaceused) for accurate space calculations.

Comment: That is an interesting query.  One of the rows in the output lists a table with 3.2GB but there are zero rows in the table.  So I'm guessing it is really an index.  The "InternalTableName" is xml_index_nodes_764581812_256000.  I'm not really sure what to make of the results.

Comment: yes, that sounds like a XML index.

Comment: I'll go learn about XML indexes but it seems strange that it needs to be bigger than everything else in the database put together.  If you want to post an an an answer I'll select it as Correct and you can have the points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Comment by  "Henrik Staun Poulsen" above pointed me in the right direction.
Half the total space used by my database is a single XML index.

I found a great article on XML Indexes here

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-xml-indexes/

I tried to rebuild the index with

```
Alter Index <IndexName> on <TableName> Rebuild
```

It ran for 5 minutes but that didn't reduce the size so I'm probably stuck with it.

I'll post the full query Henrik pointed me to here incase that link disappears in the future. (I hate that)

```
    ;WITH agg AS
(   -- Get info for Tables, Indexed Views, etc
    SELECT  ps.[object_id] AS [ObjectID],
            ps.index_id AS [IndexID],
            NULL AS [ParentIndexID],
            NULL AS [PassThroughIndexName],
            NULL AS [PassThroughIndexType],
            SUM(ps.in_row_data_page_count) AS [InRowDataPageCount],
            SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS [UsedPageCount],
            SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS [ReservedPageCount],
            SUM(ps.row_count) AS [RowCount],
            SUM(ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                    AS [LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount]
    FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
    GROUP BY    ps.[object_id],
                ps.[index_id]
    UNION ALL
    -- Get info for FullText indexes, XML indexes, Spatial indexes, etc
    SELECT  sit.[parent_id] AS [ObjectID],
            sit.[object_id] AS [IndexID],
            sit.[parent_minor_id] AS [ParentIndexID],
            sit.[name] AS [PassThroughIndexName],
            sit.[internal_type_desc] AS [PassThroughIndexType],
            0 AS [InRowDataPageCount],
            SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS [UsedPageCount],
            SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS [ReservedPageCount],
            0 AS [RowCount],
            0 AS [LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount]
    FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
    INNER JOIN  sys.internal_tables sit
            ON  sit.[object_id] = ps.[object_id]
    WHERE   sit.internal_type IN
               (202, 204, 207, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 221, 222, 236)
    GROUP BY    sit.[parent_id],
                sit.[object_id],
                sit.[parent_minor_id],
                sit.[name],
                sit.[internal_type_desc]
), spaceused AS
(
SELECT  agg.[ObjectID],
        agg.[IndexID],
        agg.[ParentIndexID],
        agg.[PassThroughIndexName],
        agg.[PassThroughIndexType],
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(agg.[ObjectID]) AS [SchemaName],
        OBJECT_NAME(agg.[ObjectID]) AS [TableName],
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN (agg.IndexID < 2) THEN agg.[RowCount]
                ELSE 0
            END) AS [Rows],
        SUM(agg.ReservedPageCount) * 8 AS [ReservedKB],
        SUM(agg.LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount +
            CASE
                WHEN (agg.IndexID < 2) THEN (agg.InRowDataPageCount)
                ELSE 0
            END) * 8 AS [DataKB],
        SUM(agg.UsedPageCount - agg.LobAndRowOverflowUsedPageCount -
            CASE
                WHEN (agg.IndexID < 2) THEN agg.InRowDataPageCount
                ELSE 0
            END) * 8 AS [IndexKB],
        SUM(agg.ReservedPageCount - agg.UsedPageCount) * 8 AS [UnusedKB],
        SUM(agg.UsedPageCount) * 8 AS [UsedKB]
FROM    agg
GROUP BY    agg.[ObjectID],
            agg.[IndexID],
            agg.[ParentIndexID],
            agg.[PassThroughIndexName],
            agg.[PassThroughIndexType],
            OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(agg.[ObjectID]),
            OBJECT_NAME(agg.[ObjectID])
)
SELECT sp.SchemaName,
       sp.TableName,
       sp.IndexID,
       CASE
         WHEN (sp.IndexID > 0) THEN COALESCE(si.[name], sp.[PassThroughIndexName])
         ELSE N'<Heap>'
       END AS [IndexName],
       sp.[PassThroughIndexName] AS [InternalTableName],
       sp.[Rows],
       sp.ReservedKB,
       (sp.ReservedKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [ReservedGB],
       sp.DataKB,
       (sp.DataKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [DataGB],
       sp.IndexKB,
       (sp.IndexKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [IndexGB],
       sp.UsedKB AS [UsedKB],
       (sp.UsedKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [UsedGB],
       sp.UnusedKB,
       (sp.UnusedKB / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [UnusedGB],
       so.[type_desc] AS [ObjectType],
       COALESCE(si.type_desc, sp.[PassThroughIndexType]) AS [IndexPrimaryType],
       sp.[PassThroughIndexType] AS [IndexSecondaryType],
       SCHEMA_ID(sp.[SchemaName]) AS [SchemaID],
       sp.ObjectID
       --,sp.ParentIndexID
FROM   spaceused sp
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects so -- in case "WHERE so.is_ms_shipped = 0" is removed
        ON so.[object_id] = sp.ObjectID
LEFT JOIN  sys.indexes si
       ON  si.[object_id] = sp.ObjectID
      AND  (si.[index_id] = sp.IndexID
         OR si.[index_id] = sp.[ParentIndexID])
WHERE so.is_ms_shipped = 0
--so.[name] LIKE N''  -- optional name filter
ORDER BY UsedGB Desc


11Jun19 Posted a question to Stack Exchange.  Didn’t use the exact queries below but something close.


16May19 This script returns information but it doesn’t add up to anything like the size of the db.

USE [MyArchive] -- replace your dbname
GO
SELECT
s.Name AS SchemaName,
t.Name AS TableName,
p.rows AS RowCounts,
CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.used_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Used_MB,
CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) / 128.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Unused_MB,
CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Total_MB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
GROUP BY t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
--ORDER BY s.Name, t.Name
Order by Total_MB
GO
```