# Table properties in SSMS and sp_spaceused don't match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table `Table_A` where when I right-click the table in SSMS and go to Properties > Storage, it shows the following:

```
Data space: 5 GB              
Index space: 250 MB
Number of partitions: 400
Partitions using default columnstore compression: 1-400
```

if I do `sp_spaceused Table_A`, it shows entirely different numbers (rounded):

```
Name    rows    reserved        data            index_size  unused
Table_A 5000000 100000000 KB    100000000 KB    25000 KB    28000 KB
```

What could be causing the difference in space consumed?

The database's properties page is showing that 100 GB reserved space as "Available", but fails to reclaim any of it during a `dbcc shrinkdb`

This table "grew" suddenly while rebuilding a clustered columnstore index where the index size grew to ~20 GB, but shrank back down after the job completed. I'm still trying to wrap my head around columnstore compression and the indexes, so I feel like I'm missing something simple

Comment: Since your question was around index rebuilds blowing it out, and the fact that you ran `DBCC SHRINKDB`, you will proably [like this post from Brent Ozar and comments by Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/) as well as [this one](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/) which references a lot of classics from Mike Walsh, Paul Randal, Gail Shaw, etc...

Comment: thanks scsimon! It's good to have some more context for this, though I believe my mystery is more about something unintentionally decompressing during the rebuild, and what actually is living in that space, if anything, after the job completes. In Brent's cases, a `SHRINKDB` actually shrinks the db, and mine do nothing. Maybe suggesting something did not re-compress after rebuilding?

Comment: Well, I posted that for the fact that rebuilding indexes need space, and shrinking causes fragmentation. So, you can get in a loop of rebuilding, shrink, crap i'm fragmented... do it all over again, etc. It's not related to your size being returned, but more so of *should you shrink at all?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data space used**

The query that gets used to calculate the data space on the table via ssms when selecting the storage properties of my `dbo.Employees` table

```
exec sp_executesql N'
        declare @PageSize float
        select @PageSize=v.low/1024.0 from master.dbo.spt_values v where v.number=@_msparam_0 and v.type=@_msparam_1



SELECT

        case
        when (tbl.is_memory_optimized=0) then
        ISNULL((select @PageSize * SUM(CASE WHEN a.type <> 1 THEN a.used_pages WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0 END)
        FROM sys.indexes as i
        JOIN sys.partitions as p ON p.object_id = i.object_id and p.index_id = i.index_id
        JOIN sys.allocation_units as a ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
        where i.object_id = tbl.object_id),0.0)
        else
        isnull((select (tms.[memory_used_by_table_kb])
        from [sys].[dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats] tms
        where tms.object_id = tbl.object_id), 0.0)
        end
       AS [DataSpaceUsed]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
WHERE
(tbl.name=@_msparam_2 and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_3)
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'1',@_msparam_1=N'E',@_msparam_2=N'Employees',@_msparam_3=N'dbo'
```

Executing this query gives me:

```
DataSpaceUsed
20008
```

This is the data in KB's, for the calculation, keep reading.

Via SSMS it gives me:

[image]

Lets explore a part of this query further, for normal, non memory optimized tables.

```
when (tbl.is_memory_optimized=0) then
        ISNULL((select @PageSize * SUM(CASE WHEN a.type <> 1 THEN a.used_pages WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0 END)
```

With the pagesize variable as a value of dbo.spt_values / 1024

```
select @PageSize=v.low/1024.0 from master.dbo.spt_values v where v.number=@_msparam_0 and v.type=@_msparam_1
```

Which can be changed to

```
    declare @PageSize float
    select @PageSize=v.low/1024.0 from master.dbo.spt_values v where v.number=1 and v.type='E'
  select @PageSize
```

= 8

Which is the 8KB page size as used by sql server

Then the next part, `CASE WHEN a.type <> 1 THEN a.used_pages`

With the type 1 being:

> 1 = In-row data (all data types, except LOB data types)

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And the next part

```
WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0
```

To get the clustered / heap data pages, without the nonclustered index pages.

So in short, get the lob data & data pages belonging to the heap or clustered index that is in `sys.allocation_units`

---

**Where does this take us?**

This gets us to link to a [different Q/A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84333/space-usage-on-sys-allocation-units-and-sp-spaceused), with the asker trying to get a performant and correct space used query by using the DMV's.

Same goes for the [other linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179417/sp-spaceused-how-to-measure-the-size-in-gb-in-all-the-tables-in-sql/26180947#26180947), both excellent answers by by [Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky)

> The following base query works. It gets the same output as
>   sp_spaceused, using the same algorithm, but much more efficiently...

So yeah, `sp_spaceused` will be more correct as the algorithm used to calculate the size accounts for more information, the query in the linked Q/A does the same but more efficiently.

You can take a look at the dmv's touched by running `sp_spaceused` with the actual execution plan enabled with **CTRL+P**, or look at [this one](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkArPQtvH), when I ran `sp_spaceused` on `dbo.Employees`

The usage of `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` in `sp_spaceused` and the query linked
vs.  the usage of `sys.allocation_units` via ssms is also apparent.

Comment: Thanks! You've answered my question about the accuracy of the storage properties. I'll have to continue to investigate what is actually sitting in that extra space when this happens.